# Calculate Week Number, Month and Year based on how long ago something was published

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Some social media platforms like YouTube do not show when a video was published. Instead, they show how long ago the video was published, which makes it particularly tricky to put it a date.

I have a formula that calculates the week number (B) based on the inpnut date, which is what the postDate column (G) is relative to.

**The expected result:**

- (1) While this is working mostly fine, I can't seem to find a way to make 11 months return "". It returns 4 weeks from the input day, which is incorrect.
- 
- (2) The same happens with years. When the post date contains a 1, it yields 1 year instead of the expected result (2012 in the case of 11 years). The formula should yield results if exact matches happen, no matter which number.

This might not be the most efficient way to calculate the month, year and week number. Also, this soluiton is not a sustainable solution as it would need to change every time new data is added to the sheet, so any alternatives to generate this input would be really useful.

[image]

Here's [a link to the worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wT3wnEbCAxATHQ_Ro5tagLOXuJ2i1GUnyfwTTyyBEqA/edit#gid=1550229028) I am using.

Here's my formula:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "(\d+)days"), 0,
  IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "(\d+)'minutes'"), 0,
   IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "(\d+)hours"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "1 day"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "2 days"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "3 days"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "4 days"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "5 days"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "6 days"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "7 days"), 0,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "8 days"), 1,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "9 days"), 1,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "10 days"), 1,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "1 week"), 1,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "2 weeks"), 2,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "3 weeks"), 3,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "4 weeks"), 4,
    IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "1 month"), 4,
     IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "2 months"), 8,
      IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "3 months"), 12,
       IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "4 months"), 16,
        IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "5 months"), 20,
         IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "6 months"), "",
          IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "7 months"), "",
           IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "8 months"), "",
            IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "9 months"), "",
             IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "10 months"), "",
              IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "'11' months"), "",
               IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "1 year"), "",
                IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "2 years"), "",
                 IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "3 years"), "",
                  IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "4 years"), "",
                   IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "5 years"), "",
                    IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "6 years"), "",
                     IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "7 years"), "",
                      IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "8 years"), "",
                       IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "9 years"), "",
                        IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "10 years"), "",
                         IF(REGEXMATCH(N11, "11 years"), "",
                          WEEK(B113, 2) - WEEK(DATE(YEAR(B113),1,1), 2) + 1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this at all, you can calculate with dates in Google sheets:

- A1 contains the date difference, e.g. "2 months"
- B1 contains this formula: `=find(" ";A1)` - it finds the splitting space between the number and the unit (day/month/year)
- C1 contains this formula: `=left(A1;B1-1)` - it gets the number from the difference and I put it into a separate field since it's used several times
- D1 contains this formula: `=lower(mid(A1;B1+1;1))` - it fetches the first letter from the unit and converts it to lowercase. Also this value is used several times subsequently
- E1 contains the main formula: `=now()-date(if(D1="y";C1;0);if(D1="m";C1;0)+1;if(D1="d";C1;0)-1)` - it subtracts the number of years/months/days from the current date. You have to **format this cell explicitly as date** (Menu Format -> Number -> Date) to see the result in a human readable form.

The main formula first converts the difference into a date, and has to make adjustments to the number of months and days.

To extend the calculation to hours and minutes etc. you have to take care that the abbreviation to just one letter is too short. Also the function to create  a time value that you can add to another is `TIME` instead of `DATE` - but you can mix the results of both within a calculation. (Times of a day are the part after the comma, before the comma is a number of days since a fixed reference date.)

BTW: For many of the services that show only the date difference, you can simply click or hover the mouse over that difference to see the actual date without conversion.